# Proof using Homomorphism between two algebraic structures , that contains two elements

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation, group-homomorphism

We have fields $(K,+,*)$ and $(L,\oplus,\otimes)$. with one's and zero elements $1_k,0_k$ and $1_l,0_l$. Suppose exists Homomorphism $f: K -> L$. Show that $f(0_k) = 0_l$ and $f(1_k) = 1_l$, if $\exists$ $a$ $\in K$,s.t $f(a)\neq 0_l$

As I understood, if $\exists$ $a$ $\in K$,s.t $f(a)\neq 0_l$ it means, that Homomorphism in our cas is isomorphism. Am I right? If so, how does it help to prove the statement above?

Comment: You have several questions here.  Just because there is some $a\in K$ s.t. $f(a)\neq 0$ does not imply that $f$ is an isomorphism.  It only implies that $f$ is nonzero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine that by "homomorphism" you mean a ring homomorphism.

Actually, since a field does not have proper ideals, you may check that any ring homomorphism from a field to any other ring is the zero morphism or it is injective (not necessarily an isomorphism!).

If there exists $a\in K$ such that $f(a)\neq 0_l$ then $f$ cannot be the zero morphism and hence it is injective.

Now,
$$f(1_k)=f(1_k* 1_k)=f(1_k)\otimes f(1_k)$$
so that $(f(1_k)-1_l)\otimes f(1_k)=0_l$. But $f(1_k)$ cannot be zero, thus $f(1_k)=1_l$.

Comment: I am sorry, I was unprecise. I meant field homomorphism

Comment: In such a case you always have an $a\in K$ such that $f(a)\neq 0_l$: it is $1_k$ itself. I mean: as far as I know, a field homomorphism is a ring homomorphism between fields which is also assumed to preserve units. Isn't it?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But one additional question. How do we know, that exacly $f(1_k)$ cannot be zero. Why not $f(0_k)$?